# Swift 4 - SpriteKit over SceneKit - prevent touch for underlying camera controls

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I'm quite new to Swift development. In my project i have a SpriteKit overlaying the SceneKit scene with allowsCameraControl set to true.

The SpriteKit layer contains buttons - what is the best way to disable the touch/pan events to trigger camera controls when these buttons are interacted with?  (e.g. double tap on a button now triggers camera reset to default position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off allowsCameraControl and implement your own camera controls instead. The allowsCameraControl is handy for testing/debugging purposes and cannot be disabled partly such as for the doubletap behavior only. Which besides conflicts with other gestures gets annoying as a double tap is easily made by accident and resets the screen.

Comment: thanks Xartec, i think this is the best way to go as there doesn't seem to be any options to control the functionality/events of the default camera control